Go array appending and deleting an element
I have a go program like this:
package main

import "fmt"

func findThreeSum(nums []int, start int, sum int, a []int, result *[][]int) {
    if sum == 0 && len(a) == 3 {
        *result = append(*result, a)
        return
    }

    if start == len(nums) || len(a) == 3 {
        return
    }

    for i := start; i < len(nums); i++ {
        a = append(a, nums[i])
        findThreeSum(nums, i+1, sum-nums[i], a, result)
        a = a[:len(a)-1]
    }
}

func threeSum(nums []int) [][]int {
    var result [][]int
    var a []int
    findThreeSum(nums, 0, 0, a, &result)

    return result
}

func main() {
    v := []int{-1, 0, 1, 2}
    r := threeSum(v)

    for i := 0; i < len(r); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d, %d, %d\n", r[i][0], r[i][1], r[i][2])
    }
}

Debugging step by step, I found that *result = append(*result, a) added the correct answer -1, 0, 1 as its first element. However, after a = a[:len(a)-1] and a = append(a, nums[i]), array "a" and the array element in "result" both changed to -1, 0, 2.
I tried to add a temporary variable and copy "a" out, then add it to "result", it came to a same result.
How should I fix the problem?
